# Is there a method for the variables from the App.Config.Settings to remain changed when I copy the program to a new PC?

Tags: c#, variables, app-config

I made a program where I declared some Application Variables with **Scope:User** and the program works fine, meaning when I change the variables while Running the .exe and after I close the program those variables remain changed.

[My app Proprieties -> Settings -> Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kt1v.png)

The goal is to be able the change the variables and then to distribute the program (.exe, .config, .pdb ) to other people so that they can use the program with the variable changed on my PC.

My main problem is whenever I change the variables on my PC and then send the Folder Archive to other people, the program sees the initial variables.

It was in my understanding that there are to .config files: one that is source and it is in the folder project and one that is saved in the C:\Users%user%\AppData\Local\

It seems that the variables that are changed on my PC are saved C:\Users%user%\AppData\Local\

So my question is: How can I approach the programming so that the variables would transfer when copying the program to a new PC?

Thank you in advance.